# php xdebug web service

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I try to use xdebug to debug my PHP web services in Eclipse Luna.

I'm able to use xdebug in a plain PHP script when debugging. But problem occurs when I try to debug a PHP service which responds to an ajax request.

In Eclipse when I lunch debugger, PHP script executes immediately. I want debugger start and wait for ajax request to execute(which is a post request from chrome rest extension).

Comment: Ok, I realized there are no problems. After I start debugging xdebug session runs for the first time but session doesn't 'end'. So I can keep using the same debug session by adding ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14641821135372 to my php web service request url.

Comment: You can also try JIT and multisession (enabled by default from 3.6 or 3.7). Once you start debugging session, all ajax requests in same browser will be handled by eclipse.